# Duplicate value in autocompletetext

Tags: android, textview, duplicates

I have an AutoCompleteText receiving information from the database. My problem is that if my table as the same value it will appear duplicate in the suggestions. Is there any sollution to only appear once??

```
List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();

public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            actv.showDropDown();
        }

public void devolvenome(){

    Cursor cursor=d.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM lol;", null);
    if(cursor.moveToLast()){
        lista.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("cam")));  
    }  
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,lista);     
    text.setThreshold(0); 
    text.setAdapter(adapter); 
    text.setTextColor(Color.RED);
}
```

Comment: read this http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html

Answer (score 1):

Try using the DISTINCT keyword in your query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM LOL;
```

The DISTINCT keyword can be used to return only distinct (different) values.

Comment: You want to return just 1 of the multiple same values from the database right? If that's correct than this should be the way to go

Comment: i tried and it didn't do anything so i tried: SELECT DISTINCT cam FROM LOL.  It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Well i just made a little adjust. I don't know if it's the most correct thing to do but it's working:

```
Cursor cursor=d.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT cam FROM lol;", null);
if(cursor.moveToLast()){
    lista.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("cam")));  
}  
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,lista);     
text.setThreshold(0); 
text.setAdapter(adapter); 
text.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```